# Phonegap not moving splash screens to build

Tags: ios, cordova

I've generated a bunch of splash screens for ios and they reside here

```
www/res/screen/ios
```

and my config.xml file has this small chunk:

```
<gap:splash gap:platform='ios' width='2008' height='1536' src='www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png' />
<gap:splash gap:platform='ios' width='1024' height='768' src='www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png' />
<gap:splash gap:platform='ios' width='1536' height='2008' src='www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png' />
<gap:splash gap:platform='ios' width='768' height='1024' src='www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png' />
<gap:splash gap:platform='ios' width='960' height='640' src='www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-2x.png' />
<gap:splash gap:platform='ios' width='480' height='320' src='www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape.png' />
<gap:splash gap:platform='ios' width='640' height='960' src='www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png' />
<gap:splash gap:platform='ios' width='320' height='480' src='www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png' />
```

but when I build, it seems that none of those images are copied to the build. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the *www* is too much. The paths should be relative to www/ already so it should look like:

```
<gap:splash gap:platform='ios' width='2008' height='1536' src='res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png' />
```

**Update**

Since I was quite sure of seeing a side note about this earlier today, I checked the documentations. These are of course claiming the opposite for PhoneGap in general and for PhoneGap Build..

[PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/config_ref_images.md.html):

> Please notice that the value of the "src" attribute is relative to the project directory and not to the www directory.

[PhoneGap Build](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html):

> src: (required) specifies the location of the image file, relative to your www directory

Comment: So what you're saying is that having them relative to the project folder and including **www** is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: What I am saying, is that since you have gap:platform='ios' there, I assume that you use PhoneGap build, for which reason you need to take the _www_ out of the paths specified as src.

Comment: Oh so sorry, just now saw that I had copied wrong quote on PhoneGap Build part.. Now it is fixed.

Comment: Looks like that's now working for android builds using their builder but when I read the logs for the iOS build, it seems that the images are not being copied.